# Owncloud: Setting an external drive as the default - Wheezy

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian-wheezy, owncloud

I'm running OwnCloud 5.0 successfully on a Raspberry Pi.  I've mounted an external 1TB harddrive, and can access it from my ownCloud.  My problem is that to access my external drive, I have to open a folder in the root of my ownCloud system called "external", or data will be written to my SD card.  Since I only plan to use the external drive, how can I set it as the default space?  I'm a newcomer to Linux (but understand basic things... apparently not where to find files, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to change the default data directory? This is extensively handled in the FAQ in the ownCloud forum here: http://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=7118

Basically, if you have already installed ownCloud, change the "datadirectory" setting in your config.php. But you have to be careful to also copy all data from the old location to the new one.

The easier option is to select "Advanced" during setup, and directly enter the desired path in the corresponding input field.